# How to update a datetime on sql azure?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I've been trying to do a simple update to a datetime column on a sql azure database to no avail, not sure why it's not working.

```
UPDATE MYDB
SET EndDate = CONVERT(datetime, '2012/12/04 24:00:00', 102)
where ItemId = 30
GO
```

**error:** The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is ok - but the time value of 24:00:00 is out of range. If you meant midnight, use 00:00:00.

Comment: Wow, didn't even think of that, thought my syntax was off for a reason on azure... thanks Brian!